# How to save and retrieve email signature by using Rich Text Box in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, email, richtextbox, signature

I wanted to create email signature for my bulk emailing software. I have tried creating a signature using Rich Text Box and it worked, but problem is after saving this in DB and when retrieving all colors and effects will be gone. 
How it will be possible to get it back as same as I created it. 
Here is what I have created. I want to retrieve this as same when going to send the mail.

[Before saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZtVf.png)

[After retrieving from DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMP8P.png)

Please kindly help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no method call richtextbox.document in winform.....please noted that my question is belong to winform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use richTextBox.Rtf to get the text with all formatting.